# Loading JS file for user in Europe (EU)

Tags: javascript, php

I am having issues with only loading this js file if a user is detected in Europe (EU):

```
if(in_array($country_code, $europe)) {
  // Europe - load JS file called ../cookiespolicy.php
} else {
  // Not Europe - ignore JS file
}

$europe = array('AD', 'AL', 'AT', 'AX', 'BA', 'BE', 'BG', 'BY', 'CH', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DK', 
'EE', 'ES', 'FI', 'FO', 'FR', 'GB', 'GG', 'GI', 'GR', 'HR', 'HU', 'IE', 'IM', 'IS', 'IT', 
'JE', 'LI', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'MC', 'MD', 'ME', 'MK', 'MT', 'NL', 'NO', 'PL', 'PT', 'RO', 
'RS', 'RU', 'SE', 'SI', 'SJ', 'SK', 'SM', 'UA', 'VA');
```

Comment: What is your "issues" ? `$europe` is undefined in your condition, because it's defined later.

Comment: Is your issue, "How do I determine a user's country?"